# How to make .exe setup in Visual Studio 2010 including Excel template files

Tags: vb.net, excel, exe

I have developed a tool that will extract data from an XML file and drops it into a formatted Excel file.

For this I have 3 types of formatted Excel files.

Whenever I'm building `.exe` file, and try to install this file on another (user's) machine, it will not find those Excel files and my code gives me an error.

How can I include those Excel files with `.exe` setup, so that I do not need to give the files separately?

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 express.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a couple of options.

1) With respect to a setup tool, Microsoft depreciated their own Setup projects and started including Install Shield Limited Edition.  This link should help if you want to check that out:  [InstallShield Limited Edition is available for download in Visual Studio 2010](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/deployment_technologies/2010/04/20/installshield-limited-edition-is-available-for-download-in-visual-studio-2010/)  I tried it for a few projects and found it ok.  It does about as much as the prior Microsoft Setup projects.

2) A less conventional option may be to package the excel templates into your exe as a resource file and then write them to the file system when you run the first time.  To do this...

1. In VS, open My Project and click the resources page on the left.
2. Click the Resources page and used the Add Resource item in the toolbar to add an existing item.  Select your excel file and repeat this for each file.
3. In your code you can save the resource to disk with code like this:

`My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllBytes("excel filename.xlsx", My.Resources.ExcelFile1, False)`

This option will understandably make your exe larger.

Comment: Thanks you it is very helpfull

Answer (score 1):

try to compile your code with [Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/)

Comment: using the free edition http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-simple.html